# database: best practice countries, country codes, country phone codes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, internationalization

I am looking for a "best practice" if you store country codes in a database but couldn't find a "this is the right way" for that. I want to store the 2 chars country code and also the country phone codes (eg Germany would be "DE" and "+49").

Actually my plan is as follows: create one table `countries`and one table with `country_codes`. Something like this:

```
TABLE: countries
id INT(11)
code CHAR(2)

TABLE: country_codes
id INT(11)
country_id INT(11) FORGEIGN KEY (countries -> id)
phone_code VARHAR(6)
```

I think I need to split them because some countries have more than one phone code. This way a country can have multiple phone codes.

But to my question: is that the "best practice" to do that? No only from that point "that will work" also more from that view if I want to rollout my application in "all" countries or if I want to translate the app in multiple languages (in that case I wanted to use the `countries` table also for the different languages.

What is your way to do thing like taht, if you want to able to translate your app in any language without the need of re-coding stuff and if you also need a list of all countries in you app?

If it should matter: I am planing to go with laravel for this app.

Comment: If a country can have multiple code then the design is correct. Now regarding lenguage: I dont see anthing needing translation my belive is the country abreviation is the same regarding lenguage

Comment: Translation was meant if I want to translate my app (not the country codes - they are always the same, yes)

Comment: keep in mind that countries can have multiple languages  like belgium uses dutch, french and german.

Comment: @RaymondNijland that is exactly what I am looking for: how to handle all infos I would need without having to much info in the db.

Comment: You need to have a complete translation table(s) not possible other wise.

Comment: Then the translation should be in a separated question

Answer (score 5):

Country codes are standardized to [two letters by ISO 3166-1-alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements), so storing them that way will work. It's often helpful to include a country name in the table, so a user can choose the right country without having to know all the codes.

Telephone numbers are far less standardized. The ITU offers [recommendation E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) for representing actual telephone numbers (called "directory numbers" in telephony jargon).   Country codes are defined as one to three digits. North America (including USA, Canada and many Carribean nations) all are part of the [North American Numbering Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan) and share the country code `1`.

Directory numbers are typically preceded by + and punctuated by dots. So, for example, the published New York City directory assistance number is (or was  when they still had such a service)  `+1.212.555.1212`. If you called that number from someplace in Europe, you would see the `+` and substitute your local international prefix. In NANP, multiple nationalities have the same country code.

But, UK is strange.  Calling from outside the country, it's `+44.exchange.number`. But calling long distance from within the country it's `(0) exchange.number`.

My point: it's hard to get it right if you try to compose directory numbers with a country code in your software. You're probably better off asking users to provide their telephone numbers with the international prefix.

You should definitely not tie E.164 country codes to ISO 3166 two-letter country codes by putting them as different columns on the same row of a table. You need two separate tables to be future proof. The standardization organizations are different and do their own things, so your data model should reflect that.

Read this:  [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Telephone Numbers](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md).

Answer (score 2):

### My DB looks like this:

```
> id    int(11) Auto Increment (Just an ID (primary key))
> iso   char(2)  (2-letters ISO code)
> name  varchar(80)  (normalized name (all uppercase))
> nicename  varchar(80)  (Nicely formatted name)
> iso3  char(3) NULL     (3-letters ISO code)
> numcode   smallint(6) NULL     (numeric ISO code)
> phonecode int(5) (phone code like '1' for USA, without '+')
```

It should be more then enough. You get user's phone number, remove zeroes at the beginning, remove any non-numerical characters, add a country code from DB and you are good to go!

Example:

1) User input (045) 111-22-33, Germany

2) You convert it to 451112233

3) Add code of Germany (49) from DB. You get 49451112233. Add '+' if you wish.

4) Now you can make a call or send SMS with Twilio or any other service.

If you want to "easily" translate the site to other languages, store all of your text in database and pull the right version depending on user's language preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers I would do the following:

DB Tables:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table: countries                                           |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| iso_code2    | char(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| iso_code3    | char(3)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| num_code     | int(3)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(48)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| nicename     | varchar(48)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
// will store all countries available


+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table: country_phonecodes                                  |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| country_id   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phonce_code  | int(6)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
// based on this page: https://countrycode.org/ there are 
// countries with more than one code 
// and also codes can be 6 chars long


+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table: languages                                           |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| code         | char(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| locale       | char(5)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| native_name  | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| flag         | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
// table for available translations of the app


+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table: country_languages                                   |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| country_id   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| language_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
// table for language suggestions for a given country
```

And some example inserts:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Inserts: countries                                                                    |
+-----+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | iso_code2  | iso_code3  | num_code  | name                | nicename            |
+-----+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1   | de         | deu        | 276       | GERMANY             | Germany             |
| 2   | do         | dom        | 214       | DOMINICAN REPUBLIC  | Dominican Republic  |
| 3   | be         | bel        | 056       | BELGIUM             | Belgium             |
+-----+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+

+----------------------------------+
| Inserts: country_phonecodes      |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| id  | country_id  | phonce_code  |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| 1   | 1           | 49           |
| 2   | 2           | 1809         |
| 3   | 2           | 1829         |
| 4   | 2           | 1849         |
| 5   | 3           | 32           |
+-----+-------------+--------------+

+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Inserts: languages                                       |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+--------------+---------+
| id  | code  | locale  | name    | native_name  | flag    |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+--------------+---------+
| 1   | de    | de_DE   | German  | Deutsch      | de.svg  |
| 2   | do    | es_DO   | Spanish | Español      | es.png  |
| 3   | be    | fr_BE   | French  | Français     | fr.jpg  |
| 4   | be    | nl_BE   | Dutch   | Nederlands   | nl.png  |
| 5   | be    | de_BE   | German  | Deutsch      | de.svg  |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+--------------+---------+

+----------------------------------+
| Inserts: country_languages       |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| id  | country_id  | language_id  |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| 1   | 1           | 1            |
| 2   | 2           | 2            |
| 3   | 3           | 3            |
| 4   | 3           | 4            |
| 5   | 3           | 5            |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
```

I think this should work and be useable for any project where a country list and/or i18n is needed.

If a user comes from Belgium, he can choose from the list of available languages/translations. He will get a suggestion for FR, NL and DE but will still be able to choose `es_DO` as prefered language.

Think this should cover all needs - but if anyone sees a problem in that or has ideas/comments: I would be happy if I can improve this solution :)

Comment: Tables country_languages and country_phonecodes doesn't need the autoincrement id. You can use pk with two columns